# Python factorial using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to find a factorial of a large number using recursion in Python 3.6. Although I have set the recursion limit to 10**9, still running the code makes the kernel go dead. I know that iterative solutions are much better, yet I wanted to know the reason for this

```
import sys
mod = 10**9+7
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**9) 
def fac(n):
    if(n == 1):
        return 1
    return (fac(n-1)%mod*n%mod)%mod 
print(fac(10000))
```

Comment: The standard basis case for factorial is 0, not 1.  Your code fails for 0!.  Also, you have grouping problems, so in effect the final `%` does nothing.  You need to add parentheses around `(n%mod)` if you want it to do what you intend.  Also, it makes no sense to use recursion for factorial.  It's a simple iteration.  You shouldn't need to increase the stack limit at all.  Factorial is not a good candidate for recursion.

Comment: can you explain `mod`? why not `fac(n-1)*n`? Is `mod` needed to demonstrate the stack overflow?

Comment: Not using mod will generate really large numbers with higher n leading to very slow implementation. Try the above code without mod for say n= 10000 or so.

Answer (score 1):

Calculating factorial of such a large number results in **overflow in stack memory** as whenever we apply recursion all recursive calls get their own memory getting stacked over one another.

Therefore for such a large number, the recursive stack grows bigger and bigger with recursive calls resulting in **stack overflow**

That's why Kernel dies producing no results